# URI scheme for URI schemes

Tags: uri, semantic-web

Is there a URI or URN syntax that allows identifying particular URI schemes by their name? I could of course use an "example" URI like `http://example.org` for encoding the scheme in a URI, but that is not explicit in referring to the scheme and not the resource. Using only the scheme name with `:` also does not help much, since for example `tv:` alone does have a meaning in its scheme.

I am aware such URIs could be ambiguous, so something like `urn:urischeme:xyz` could mean different things on machines that assign arbitrary meanings to the `xyz:` scheme, however that is already true for any normal URI in the scheme. I am fine with `urn:urischeme:xyz` having precisely the meaning of the scheme of any `xyz:` URI, whatever that would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems [uri4uri](https://w3id.org/uri4uri/) offers a sufficient way to identify any URI scheme, as well as domains, MIME types and file extensions. For example: [`https://w3id.org/uri4uri/scheme/urn`](https://w3id.org/uri4uri/scheme/urn).